# Help with Partial Differential Equation Arising from Generating Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, generating-functions

I am considering a sequence of polynomials ${f_0}(x), {f_1}(x), {f_2}(x)\dots$ satisfying the recursive property ${f_k}(x)=(x^2+1){f_{k-1}}'(x)$, where ${f_0}(x)=x$.

Define $F(x,y)=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n! } { f }_{ n }(x){ y }^{ n } } $, the exponential generating function for ${f_k}(x)$.

Using standard techniques, I found that $F(x,y)=x+(x^{ 2 }+1)\int { \frac { \partial F }{ \partial x } dy }$ (this might be wrong as I'm not terribly familiar with generating functions, but my question stands nonetheless).

My question is if there is there exists a (preferably nice) general solution to the above PDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x,y)=\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n! } { f }_{ n }(x){ y }^{ n } } $$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ n! } { f }_{ n }(x)n{ y }^{ n-1 } } = \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ (n-1)! } { f }_{ n }(x){ y }^{ n-1 } }$$
${f_n}(x)=(x^2+1){f_{n-1}}'(x)$, where ${f_0}(x)=x$.
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ (n-1)! }(x^2+1) { f _{ n-1 }}'(x){ y }^{ n-1 } } = (x^2+1)\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ (n-1)! }  { f _{ n-1 }}'(x){ y }^{ n-1 } }$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =(x^2+1)\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ k! }  { f _{ k }}'(x){ y }^{ k } }$$
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { 1 }{ k! }  { f _{ k }}'(x){ y }^{ k } } \quad\to\quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =(x^2+1)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$
$$(x^2+1)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$
Solving this PDE:

Set of characteristic ODEs : $\quad \frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dF}{0}$.

From $dF=0 \to$ equation of a first family of characteristic curves : $\quad F=c_1$

From $\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=y \to$ equation of a second family of characteristic curves : $\quad \tan^{-1}(x)-y=c_2$

General solution of the PDE :
$$F(x,y)=\Phi\left(\tan^{-1}(x)-y \right) \tag 1$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function.

Condition :  $F(x,0)=f_0(x)=x \quad\to\quad \Phi\left(\tan^{-1}(x)-0 \right)=x$

Let $t=\tan^{-1}(x)\quad\to\quad \Phi\left(t \right)=\tan(t)$

So, the function $\phi$ is known and can be put into (1) :
$$F(x,y)=\tan\left(\tan^{-1}(x)-y \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

After differentiating in $y$, you get the PDE $(x^2+1)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$.  The ODE for the characteristic curves is $\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=dy$, or $d(y-\arctan(x))=0$, so $F(x,y)=\Phi(y-\arctan(x))$ is the general solution, which you could place in the equivalent form
$$
F(x,y)=\Phi\left(\frac{\tan y-x}{1+x\tan y}\right).
$$
Here, $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function.  Not sure how nice it is, but it's explicit!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A couple of questions:

1. Does differentiating in $y$ produce extraneous solutions, and
2. How did you determine that $y-\arctan { x } =\frac { \tan { y } -x }{ 1+x\tan { y }  }$?

Comment: @Richard In response to 2, it doesn't. The right hand side is obtained by taking the tangent of the left hand side and using the tangent subtraction formula. The tangent can then be absorbed into the function $\Phi$.

Comment: @StackOverflown Thanks, that makes sense. First question still stands, though.

Comment: In response to (1), differentiating only produces extraneous solutions if your integral was definite.  For example, does $\int \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dy$ mean $\int_0^y\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,t)dt$, or is it simply an indefinite integral?  If the latter, then the equation was already undefined up to a function $g(x)$, so any redundancy caused by taking $\partial/\partial y$ of this equation already existed beforehand.